# How to get the value of the discrimiator from a TPH collection in EF4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have an abstract parent entity with 6 inherited child entities, using TPH in EF4.

Is there a simple way to get the value of the dicriminator column, bearing in mind that although at the moment it is the same as the Type.Name, this does not have to be the case.

In my case, I am importing data from many sources into a single table for processing - so the **Disc** is very useful so I only have one table, which I can expand to take in many sources.

I'd like to be able to simply loop through the collection and get the value of the discriminator - I would have thought that should be possible/sensible?

Comment: Is not the discriminator the FK in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discriminator column is represented by the type of the entity so you can use:

```
foreach (var entity in context.MyTPHEntities.OfType<SubtypeA>())
{
    ...
}
```

To get all SubtypeA instances in your TPH hierarchy or

```
foreach (var entity in context.MyTPHEntities)
{
    if (entity is SubtypeA)
    { 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

To work with all entities and their types = discriminator values.

Discriminator cannot be mapped as a property so you cannot get its value directly without diving deep into `MetadataWorkspace` and traversing mapping at runtime - that would require some time spend in debugger to find a way for retrieving the mapped value. Still you will not be able to use discriminator column in LINQ queries or for inserting new entity via EF. It can be only useful for native SQL access.

Comment: Thanks: However, you CAN change the value of the discriminator in the model - I generated my model by TPT using DatabaseFirst and then added the hierarchy separately afterwards - which means I could put whatever I like in the "Where" clause.

Comment: So are you using TPT or TPH? Those are two different mappings and discriminator in TPH cannot be exposed as a property and thus cannot be used in LINQ `where`.

Comment: Originally generated TPT, but added a hierarchy and re-generated DB from Model TPH.  However, you can set the value used for the discriminator in the mappings, so it doesn't HAVE to be the Type...just helps if it is!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop trough your table and just read the discriminator column you could use an EntityReader to do this.

Check out the following information: [How to: Execute a query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716751.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I was hoping for:  At the moment I import multiple data sources into the collection then process it - any that are "wrong" get removed and a new item added to an "error" collection.  Only when the collection is processed do I call SaveChanges().  The Query way would require saving first, then re-processing the list.  Guess I can just add a matching column with the name in it that IS part of the model.